# MIDL (Constant) References

Tags: windows, com, midl

Are there no constant references in MIDL method declarations????

eg.

```
[id(1), helpstring("My Method")]
HRESULT MyMethod(
    [in] IID & const rclsid
);
```

for

```
HRESULT MyMethod(
    IID const &rclsid
);
```

Comment: d3d11.idl uses REFGUID :/  I don't know how to feel about this 

o~o

rather good I guess 'cause it works; question still stands though 'cause I don't see how REFGUID is even possible if you can't and yet I can't seem to nor find an example......

Comment: What did Paul change??  Did I use an is instead of an are???  I do that sometimes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MIDL doesn't really support reference parameters, it only supports "in" and "out" parameters.  So if you DO pass in a reference, it's just syntactic sugar for a pointer to the value (the issue is observability - if you have a callback function or interface in our method signature, changes to a reference would be observable from the callback, but changes to an [out] parameter aren't visible until the function returns.

In addition, the difference between "& const" and "const &" are lost.  If you look at the definition of REFGUID, you'll see that they only use one form of "const" for C++ code:

```
#ifdef __midl_proxy
#define __MIDL_CONST
#else
#define __MIDL_CONST const
#endif

#ifndef _REFGUID_DEFINED
#define _REFGUID_DEFINED
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define REFGUID const GUID &
#else
#define REFGUID const GUID * __MIDL_CONST
#endif
#endif
```